# Create filter table by day

Tags: google-bigquery

Good afternoon,
I would like to know how to create a table that I can filter by day, when creating the table it will appear at the top of the table, a filter that can select the day, there it shows the data for the day.

I don't know if the question was easy to understand.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Thiago, you can do that with a classical `sql` query, why do you want to add a filter directly on a table ?

Comment: Yes, by sql I can, directly in the table, it is a user request, with that I wanted to understand how to create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it’s not possible to create a table on BigQuery with an interactive filter on it.

However you can create a `Datastudio/Looker studio` dashboard on your table and expose it to your users.

In this dashboard you can add a [date control field](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/6291067?hl=en) that allows to select a date range on your column.

In this date control you may add a default value on today.

You have to be careful on the cost of processed data and use a partition on your date column in the table.